# Discrete Math Functions on infinity

Tags: functions

Here is a question I had from a previous exam.

*Let $A = (-\infty,0]$, $B = (9,\infty)$, and $f(x) = 3^x.$*
*Find $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$.*

All and any help guiding me through this would really help. I'm completely lost and not sure what I should be doing here with these sets. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know Calculus? How to work with limits?

Comment: @AdriánNaranjo Yes, im familiar. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the direct image of $-\infty,0].$ Note that $f$ is increasing, $f(0)=1$ and $f(-\infty):=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to -\infty} 3^x=0$ so $f[[9,+\infty)]=(0,1]$.

Now, you need to calculate the inverse image of $[9,+\infty)$. That is, the values of $x$ such that $9\leq 3^x <\infty$, which are $2\leq x<\infty$, so $f^{-1}[[9,+\infty)]=[2,+\infty )$.

Comment: ah thanks a lot!

Comment: You're very welcome!